# SwipeLayout и NullPointerException

Tags: android, swipelayout

Здравствуйте. Я использую библиотеку [SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/). Прикрепил её на `RecyclerView`, каждая строчка которого отображает `CardView`. Анимация и свайп работают прекрасно.

**Проблема №1:** Если в теле фрагмента ReyclerView посадить на `addOnItemTouchListener` и задать ему какое-то действие, то это действие работает правильно. Если "свайпнуть"(сдвинуть CardView), то появляется кнопка. Если на неё нажать, то вместо задачи этой кнопки выполняется действие, которое было задано на `addOnItemTouchListener` моего ReyclerView'а. Другими словами, тач листнер перекрывает кнопку выезжающую кнопку.

**Возможное решение:** каким-то образом проверить сдвинут ли сейчас CardView или нет. И отталкиваясь от этого включить/выключить итем тач лиснтер, чтобы не блокировал выезжающий элемент.

**Проблема №2:** Нажатия можно обработать в теле адаптера, здесь вроде тоже всё неплохо работает, но при вызове метода(который заменяет фрагментА на фрагментБ) из фрагметаА вылетает **java.lang.NullPointerException**. Пытался разобраться в чём проблема опираясь на [статью с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/221243/) об этих исключениях, но ни к чему не привело. Вот код метода из фрагметаА, который я пытаюсь вызвать:

```
   public  void perehod(){
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SettingsFilter settingsFilter = new SettingsFilter();
        ftrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, settingsFilter);
        ftrans.addToBackStack(null);
        ftrans.commit();
    }
```

Вот код адаптера:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout;
import com.daimajia.swipe.adapters.RecyclerSwipeAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.myApp.R;
import com.myApp.frags.FilterFrag;

public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {

    FilterFrag filterFrag;
    private Context mContext;
    private static ArrayList<String> region;
    public static String myItem;
    static  FilterFrag myFilter;

    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        this.mContext = context;
        region = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swipe_row_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final String item = region.get(position);

        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(region.get(position));


        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);


        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setLeftSwipeEnabled(false);

        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                //you are swiping.

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the BottomView totally show.

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {

            }
        });


        viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myItem = region.get(position);     
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//-------------------Здесь вызываю метод-----------------------   
                myFilter.perehod();
//---------------------------------------------------------
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        });


        viewHolder.btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Клик на выезжающем элементе", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return region.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    } 

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        public TextView mTextView;

        ImageButton btnLocation;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filter_recycler_tv);

            btnLocation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

        }
    }
    public static String getValue(int position) {
        return region.get(position);
    }
}
```

Вот лог:

> 04-16 19:06:54.250 5320-5320/com.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at
>   com.myApp.Adapters.SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter$2.onClick(SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:117)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы 1) попробуйте сделать так

```
public class SingleTapGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Добавте его как проперти в адаптер `private GestureDetector gestureDetector;`, затем проинициализируйте его в конструкторе адаптера `gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new SingleTapGestureDetector());`,
а потом используйте его в setOnTouchListener

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                //item touch action
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

2) почему бы вам не передать листенер в адаптер и вызывать метод листенера к примеру так `listener.perehod()`, а фрагмент пускай уже имплементит этот листенер. Я так понимаю этот адаптер объявлен во фрагменте, который в данный момент находится у вас как статическое поле в адаптере. Адаптер не должен содержать ссылки на фрагменты, он отвечает только за наполнение recyclerView. И у вас инициализирован `static  FilterFrag myFilter;` ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Могли бы Вы немного объяснить по поводу второго решения? У меня вроде нет ссылок на фрагмент, я только вызываю метод из фрагмента(который меняет фрагменты). FilterFrag(это фрагмент)  у меня инициализирован в адаптере. Но при вызове `myFilter.perehod();`  вылетает ошибка. Да, адаптер объявлен в теле фрагмента и заполняет его.

Comment: из куска кода для вашего адаптера, я могу сделать вывод что myFilter у  вас null, потому что нет места где бы вы его проинициализировали. static  FilterFrag myFilter; это и есть ссылка на фрагмент и ина не инициализированна